# Correction request for C Program

Tags: c

// I'm having issues compiling my program. Honestly, i'm a new programmer and i'm not really sure how to use certain things within my program. Can someone check my program and give me the corrections please or better thoroghly explain it ti me? It's neede for monday..//

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{

    //File declarations//

    FILE*Log;
    FILE*Inventory;
    FILE*Username;

    char fpass_word[10]="invent";
    char fusername[10]="";

    //Declarations for variables//
    int main;
    int sub_main;
        int s=0;
        int s_goods;
        int p_goods;
        int in_goods;
    int c_goods;
    double Unit_price;
    int item_quantity;
    int invoice_num;
    char pass_word1[10]=" ";
    char pass_word[10]="invent";
    char username[10]="inventor";
    char username1[10]=" ";
    char Supplier[12]=" ";
    char Items_name[12]=" ";  
    char Invoice_date[10]=" ";   

    //Declarations for variables//
   int u=0;
   int count=0;
   int option;
   int choice;
   int choice1;
   int m=0;
   int Save;
   int New_inventory;
   int Update_inventory;
   int Print;
   int Close_Program;
   int t_sales;
   int t_purchases;
   double m_sales[4]={30000.00,50000.00,100000.00,120000.00};
}

   Log=fopen("Invent.txt","w")

   if(Log==NULL)

     printf("File does not exist");
     }
   else
     {
       fprintf(Log,"%s",pass_word);
       fclose(Log);
     }

   user=fopen("Username.txt","w")

   if(user==NULL)
   {
     printf("File does not exist");
   }
   else
   {
       fprintf(user,"%s",username);
       fclose(user);
   }
   printf("__________________________________________________________\n\n");
   printf("************Please login to your account!************\n\n");
   printf("__________________________________________________________\n\n");

   printf("Please enter your username: \n");
   scanf("%s",username);

   user=fopen("Username.txt","r")
   {
   if(user==NULL)
   {
     printf("File does not exist");
   }
   else
   {
       fprintf(user,"%s",fusername);
       fclose(user);
   }
   choice1=strncmp(username,fusername,10);

   printf("Please enter password: \n");
   scanf("%s",pass_word1);

   Log=fopen("Invent.txt","r")

   if(Log==NULL)
   {
     printf("File does not exist");
   }
   else
   {
       fscanf(Log,"%s",fpass_word);
       fclose(Log);
   }

   choice=strncmp(pass_word1,fpass_word,10);


  while (choice!=0 && count<3)
  {
    printf("*************************************************************************************\n\n");
    printf("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Please re-enter your login info!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
    printf("*************************************************************************************\n\n");

    printf(" Please enter username: \n");
    scanf("%s",&username);

    choice=strncmp(username,username1,10);

    printf("Please enter password!\npassword:");
    scanf("%s",pass_word);

    choice=strncmp(pass_word,pass_word1,10);

    count=count++;

    //menu function!!!
    getch();
    system("cls");

 }//login page

    printf("\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
    printf("\n******************** Welcome to the INVENT BIZ main page!********************\n\n");
    printf("\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n\n");
    printf (">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Please select an option you desire:<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n\n");

    printf("1: New inventory\n");
    printf("2: Update inventory\n");
    printf("3: Print\n");
    printf("4: Save \n");
    printf("5: Close Program\n");
    printf("Please select an option: \n");
    scanf("%d",&option);

//menu screen
   while(option!=6)
   {

   switch(main)
   {
       case 1:

              printf("New inventory");

              Inventory=fopen("New Inventory.txt","w")


          if (Inventory==NULL)

          printf("This File is empty!");

          }
          else
          {

            fprintf("Please enter invoice date:\t\n");
            fprintf("Please enter Supplier:\t\n");            
            fprintf("Please enter Item name:\t\n");              
            fprintf("Please enter quantity of items:\t\n");            
            fprintf(" Please enter invoice number:\t\n");            
            fprintf("Please enter Unit Price:\t\n");              
          }
          fclose(Inventory);

      // Data entered for inventory//



switch(sub-main)
        {
         case 10:

                  printf("Please enter sales for each month:%d",t_sales);
                  printf(" Total Sales\n");
                  scanf("%d",&t_sales);

        break;

         case 3:
                 printf("Print");

                    Inventory=fopen("New Inventory.txt","r")

                     fscanf(Inventory,"%d",Invoice_date);
                     fscanf(Inventory,"%s",Supplier);
                     fscanf(Inventory,"%s",Items_name);
                     fscanf(Inventory,"%d",&item_quantity);
                     fscanf(Inventory,"%d",&invoice_num);
                     fscanf(Inventory,"%d",&Unit_price);

                     fclose(Inventory);

                  break;
         case 4:
                 printf("Save");

              Inventory=fopen("Inventory1.txt","w");

              if(Inventory==NULL)
              {
                  printf("This file empty!!!");
              }
                else
                    {
                        printf("File saved");
                    }
                fclose(Inventory);
      case 5:
              printf("Close Program");

              exit(main);

              break;
} // end switch

    system("cls");

    printf (">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Please select an option you desire!!!<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n\n");

    printf("1: New inventory\n");
    printf("2: Update inventory\n");
    printf("3: Print\n");
    printf("4: Save \n");
    printf("Please select an option: \n");
    scanf("%d",&option);
   }
}
system("cls");
getch();
return ();
}
```

Comment: Unless you tell us what the problem is and what your program is intended to do, we can't help you.  You might also want to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does it compile and run?

Comment: This isn't the kind of question that this site is here for. If your code is broken, describe the problem you're having. You haven't indicated anything is broken though, just "check this out and tell me what to change" -- not a bad thought in terms of your wanting to learn, but not appropriate here. The site in @RickS's comment may be more helpful for you.

Comment: You are missing a lot of `}` for example line after `double m_sales[4] = {30000.00, 50000.00, 100000.00, 120000.00};` the `}` close the main. This program don't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be more specific and not just throw down an entire program and say you want to someone to clean it up for you.

Thank being said I noticed right away you had a few improperly placed curly braces. Your very first `if` statement is missing an opening brace and further down you have an unnecessary opening brace after `user=fopen("Username.txt", "r")`

Beyond that indentation is completely off throughout and your `switch` statements make it really hard to follow what it is you're trying to accomplish with them.

My advice is to read through the compiler errors and locate each issue one by one, and if you're having a problem you can't solve then be specific and post the errors you're getting with your program.